# Serre duality and cluster categories

Tags: ct.category-theory

I just started reading about the Cluster categories. I don't understand these questions?
1- Why Serre duality is so important? and why we write $Hom(X,Y[1]) \cong DHom(Y, \tau X)$? We can write $Hom(X,Y[1]) \cong Hom(Y, \tau X)$?
2- Why do we identify objects with their orbits, when we move from the derived category to the cluster category?
Thanks

Comment: Have you read anything about Auslander-Reiten theory in general beforehand?  This would give some context to $\tau$ and the linear duality $D$. Then the cluster category is by definition an orbit category, imposing a relation between $\tau$ and D. Precisely why this relation is the right thing to do is an interesting and not obvious question.

Comment: The isomorphism $\operatorname{Hom}(X,Y[1])\cong\mathrm{D}\operatorname{Hom}(Y,\tau X)$ is an isomorphism of functors (in either $X$ or $Y$), whereas one only has $\operatorname{Hom}(X,Y[1])\cong\operatorname{Hom}(Y,\tau X)$ as vector spaces—there can't be an isomorphism of functors in the second case because the variances disagree. This is the reason for preferring the former.